# Base Tag in Structured Testing Tool

Tags: html, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags, google-rich-snippets, structured-data

if i put

```
<head>
<base href="http://www.domain.com" />
<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>
<meta property="og:title" content="Title"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="description"/>
</head>
```

in the [Structured Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool?hl=en) the follow error message is shown:
**Unspecified Type**
if i remove the line `<base href="http://www.domain.com" />`it is fine.
I need the `<base>` tag.
Whats wrong or what can i do to validate with the base-tag?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

- If I put the source code of my site in the testing tool, the error
  message above comes.
- If I fetch the original URL with the tool,
  everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change head tag like below:

```
<head typeof="og:article">
```